# I need speech recognition software for Ubuntu (like "Dragon NaturallySpeaking 13 professional" for Windows)

Tags: accessibility, speech-recognition

I am disabled and use Dragon NaturallySpeaking version 13 professional in order to use my computer.

It does not play well under Wine and is the only thing stopping me from completely switching to Linux, which is a real shame, but unfortunately something that cannot be helped.

Can anybody help me to make my Software run on Ubuntu or suggest me an equal alternative?

Comment: I use DNS and although voice recognition has improved, it still lags in linux. You can look at pocket sphinx, but I am going to guess it will not meet all your needs. It is in the repositories, but may require manual configuration. Probably the best link - http://thenerdshow.com/freespeech.html

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is you try native applications like Gnu/Linux.

### Simon Speech Recognition:

Simon is highly configurable, targeted speech recognition software. Simon features a whole new recognition layer, context-awareness for improved accuracy and performance, a dialog system able to hold whole conversations with the user and more.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install simon
```

### CMU Sphinx:

CMU Sphinx is a speaker-independent large vocabulary continuous speech recognizer released under BSD style license. It is also a collection of open source tools and resources that allows researchers and developers to build speech recognition systems.

[Download Page](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/download)